# Parse context from Task to DAG in case of success or failure

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

There are multiple tasks running inside a DAG according to below code.

```py
import logging
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from util.email_util import Email
from util.slack_alert_util import task_failure_alert
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.postgres_operator import PostgresOperator


def dag_failure_notification_alert(context):
    # Slack notification
    logging.info("Sending DAG Slack notification")
    task_failure_alert(context)

    # Email notification
    subject = 'DAG Failure Alert'
    from_email = 'abcd@xyz.com'
    to_email = ['abcd@xyz.com']
    dag_name = str(context['dag'])[6:-1]
    dag_run = str(context['dag_run'])[8:-1]
    message_body = """
                    <html>
                        <body>
                        <strong>Airflow DAG Failure Report</strong><br /><br />
                        Dag Name: {}<br />
                        Dag run details: {}<br />
                        Execution date and time: {}<br />
                        Run ID: {}<br />
                        Task Instance Key: {}<br />
                        Exception: {}<br />
                        </body>
                    </html>
                    """.format(dag_name, dag_run, str(context['execution_date']), str(context['run_id']),
                               str(context['task_instance_key_str']), str(context.get('exception')))
    logging.info("Message body created for DAG as: %s", message_body)
    email_obj = Email(
        {'Subject': subject, 'From': from_email, 'To': to_email, 'body': message_body, 'file': None, 'filename': '',
         'body_type': 'html'})
    email_obj.send()


def task_failure_notification_alert(context):
    # Slack notification
    logging.info("Sending Task Slack notification")
    task_failure_alert(context)


default_args = {
    "owner": "analytics",
    "start_date": datetime(2021, 12, 12),
    'retries': 0,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(),
    "schedule_interval": "@daily"
}

dag = DAG('test_alert_notification',
          default_args=default_args,
          catchup=False,
          on_failure_callback=dag_failure_notification_alert
          )

start_task = DummyOperator(task_id="start_task", dag=dag, on_failure_callback=task_failure_notification_alert)
end_task = DummyOperator(task_id="end_task", dag=dag, on_failure_callback=task_failure_notification_alert)

create_table_sql_query = '''
CREATE TABLE dummy_table (id INT NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL);
'''
for i in range(5):
    create_table_task = PostgresOperator(
        sql=create_table_sql_query,
        task_id=str(i),
        postgres_conn_id="postgres_dummy_test",
        dag=dag,
        on_failure_callback=task_failure_notification_alert
    )
    start_task >> create_table_task >> end_task
```

DAG graph according to the above code.

[image]

As we can see in the above DAG graph image that if parallel Postgres tasks i.e. 0,1,2,3,4 is failing then on_failure_callback will call the python function(task_failure_notification_alert) with context to send a slack notification.

In the end, it is sending slack and email notifications both in case of DAG failure with context having on_failure_callback with dag_failure_notification_alert function call.

In case of Task failure,

The output seems to be like this:

```
DAG FAIL ALERT
    dag: <DAG: test_alert_notification>,
    dag_run: <DagRun test_alert_notification @ 2022-11-29 12:03:13.245324+00:00: manual__2022-11-29T12:03:13.245324+00:00, externally triggered: True>,
    execution_date: 2022-11-29T12:03:13.245324+00:00,
    run_id: manual__2022-11-29T12:03:13.245324+00:00,
    task_instance_key_str: test_alert_notification__4__20221129
    exception: The conn_id postgres_dummy_test isn't defined
```

or

```
DAG FAIL ALERT
    dag: <DAG: test_alert_notification>,
    dag_run: <DagRun test_alert_notification @ 2022-11-29 12:03:13.245324+00:00: manual__2022-11-29T12:03:13.245324+00:00, externally triggered: True>,
    execution_date: 2022-11-29T12:03:13.245324+00:00,
    run_id: manual__2022-11-29T12:03:13.245324+00:00,
    task_instance_key_str: test_alert_notification__5__20221129
    exception: The conn_id postgres_dummy_test isn't defined
```

for each different task.

In DAG failure, the context contains an exception as None and only a single task instance key which is the last success ID.

**DAG failure Output format:**

```
DAG FAIL ALERT
    dag: <DAG: test_alert_notification>,
    dag_run: <DagRun test_alert_notification @ 2022-11-30 09:33:02.032456+00:00: manual__2022-11-30T09:33:02.032456+00:00, externally triggered: True>,
    execution_date: 2022-11-30T09:33:02.032456+00:00,
    run_id: manual__2022-11-30T09:33:02.032456+00:00,
    task_instance_key_str: test_alert_notification__start_task__20221130
    exception: None
```

I want to pass task failure information i.e exceptions and task instances todag_failure_notification_alert to send an email with accumulated information of all failure tasks.

1. I tried using a common global variable i.e. exceptions and task_instances as a list and appending all task exceptions and task instances to it inside the task_failure_notification_alert function. Later using the same variable inside the dag_failure_notification_alert function but it didn't work.
2. I tried using python callback as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73991675/on-failure-callback-triggered-multiple-times) but it works with PythonOperator only.
3. I read about [XCOM](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/xcoms.html) push and pull mechanism but it focuses on sharing data between tasks(if I understand it correctly) and unsure how to use it here.

As I am new to this Airflow. Kindly suggest the best way to do it. Any other method which suits best for this kind of requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I find for it from the [stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74017209/9166673).
We can get the list of failed tasks by using passed context only.

e.g.

```py
ti = context['task_instance']
for t in ti.get_dagrun().get_task_instances(state=TaskInstanceState.FAILED):  # type: TaskInstance
logging.info(f'failed dag: {t.dag_id}, task: {t.task_id}, url: {t.log_url}')
```

Updating the `dag_failure_notification_alert` as

```py
def dag_failure_notification_alert(context):
    # Slack notification
    logging.info("Sending DAG Slack notification")
    task_failure_alert(context)

    failed_tasks = []
    dag_name = None
    ti = context['task_instance']
    for t in ti.get_dagrun().get_task_instances(state=TaskInstanceState.FAILED):  # type: TaskInstance
        logging.info(f'failed dag: {t.dag_id}, task: {t.task_id}, url: {t.log_url}')
        dag_name = t.dag_id
        failed_tasks.append({'id': t.task_id, 'url': t.log_url})

    if failed_tasks:
        # Email notification
        subject = 'DAG Failure Alert'
        from_email = 'abcd@xyz.com'
        to_email = ['abcd@xyz.com']
        task_url_link = ""
        for failed_task in failed_tasks:
            task_url_link += """<a href="{}">{}</a>, """.format(failed_task['url'], failed_task['id'])
        task_url_link = task_url_link[:-2]
        message_body = """
                        <html>
                            <body>
                            <strong>Airflow DAG Failure Report</strong><br /><br />
                            <b>Dag Name:</b> {}<br />
                            <b>Task Details:</b> [{}]<br />
                            <br />
                            Thanks,<br />
                            </body>
                        </html>
                        """.format(dag_name, task_url_link)
        logging.info("Message body created for DAG as: %s", message_body)
        email_obj = Email(
            {'Subject': subject, 'From': from_email, 'To': to_email, 'body': message_body, 'file': None, 'filename': '',
             'body_type': 'html'})
        email_obj.send()
    else:
        logging.info("No failure Tasks fetched.")
```

Hope this will help anyone if someone faces the same issue that's why I post the answer.